# Delayed Job Rake Task Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I'm trying to get delayed job to work as a rake task, but for the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Given the following setup:

```
#config/environment.rb
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.gem 'delayed_job'
end

#Rakefile
begin
    require 'delayed/tasks'
rescue LoadError
    STDERR.puts "Run `rake gems:install` to install delayed_job"
end

#Observer
class SomeObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
   def foo(bar)
   end
   handle_asynchronously :foo
end
```

Whenever I run rake jobs:clear I get the following error:

```
undefined method `handle_asynchronously' for SomeObserver:Class
```

Even though I don't get this error when I'm running the test cases or it directly.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DelayedJob defines `handle_asynchronously` in `Delayed::MessageSending::ClassMethods`. DelayedJob automatically monkey-patches that module into `Module` in its `lib/delayed_job.rb`. You'll likely have better luck requiring that in your Rake task:

```
#Rakefile
begin
  require 'delayed_job'
  require 'delayed/tasks'
rescue LoadError
  STDERR.puts "Run `rake gems:install` to install delayed_job"
end
```