# Delayed_job: undefined method `handle_asynchronously' for #<Class:0x4601b08>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

After deploying `DelayedJob` as a gem, I got the following error:

```
undefined method `handle_asynchronously' for #<Class:0x4601b08>
```

Same code works when I deploy DelayedJob as a plugin.

I have tried the solution suggested by this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161163/delayed-job-rake-task-failing) and I still get the same error.

I am using DelayedJob 1.8.4, Windows XP, Rails 2.3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a model called `DelayedJob` in my models directory. I added this model to query the job queue. This conflicted with the `delayed_job.rb` file. I renamed the file and the problem went away.